# Reading pipe asynchronously using ReadFile

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, named-pipes

I think I need some clarification on how to read from a named pipe and have it return immediately, data or not.  What I am seeing is ReadFile fails, as expected, but GetLastError returns either ERROR_IO_PENDING or ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED, and it does this until my surrounding code times out.  I get these errors EVEN THOUGH THE DATA HAS IN FACT ARRIVED. I know this by checking my read buffer and seeing what I expect. And the pipe keeps working. I suspect I am not using the overlapped structure correctly, I'm just setting all fields to zero.  My code looks like this:

```
gPipe = CreateFile(gPipename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
pMode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE; 
bret = SetNamedPipeHandleState(gPipe, &pMode, NULL, NULL);

OVERLAPPED ol;
memset(&ol, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

// the following inside a loop that times out after a period
bret = ReadFile(gPipe, &tmostat, sizeof(TMO64STAT), NULL, &ol);
if (bret) break;
err = GetLastError();
// seeing err == ERROR_IO_PENDING or ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED
```

So I can do what I want by ignoring the errors and checking for arrived data, but it troubles me.  Any idea why I am getting this behavior?

Comment: `ERROR_PIPE_NOT_CONNECTED` is error, mean that pipe in bad state and `ReadFile` complete and fail. `ERROR_IO_PENDING` mean that `ReadFile` mean that operation begin and not completed yet. you need check data only after it completed. ignoring return value/error and check data is error

Answer (score 1):

Windows OVERLAPPED I/O doesn't work like the non-blocking flag on other OSes (For example on Linux, the closest equivalent is `aio_*()` API, not `FIONBIO`)

With OVERLAPPED I/O, the operation hasn't failed, it proceeds in the background.  But you are never checking on it... you just try again.  There's a queue of pending operations, you're always starting new ones, never checking on the old ones.

Fill in the `hEvent` field in the OVERLAPPED structure, and use it to detect when the operation completes.  Then call `GetOverlappedResult()` to get the number of bytes actually transferred.

Another important note -- the OS owns the OVERLAPPED structure and the buffer until the operation completes, you must take care to make sure these stay valid and not deallocate them or use them for any other operation until you confirm that the first operation completed.

---

Note that there is an actual non-blocking mode for Win32 pipes, but Microsoft strongly recommends against using it:

> The nonblocking-wait mode is supported for compatibility with Microsoft LAN Manager version 2.0. This mode should not be used to achieve overlapped input and output (I/O) with named pipes. Overlapped I/O should be used instead, because it enables time-consuming operations to run in the background after the function returns.

- [Named Pipe Type, Read, and Wait Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipe-type-read-and-wait-modes)

Comment: use `hEvent` with `GetOverlappedResult` is one from 3 ways. and worst. another way use apc completion with `ReadFileEx`. third way - bind `hFile` to iocp - or via `BindIoCompletionCallback` or (vista+) `CreateThreadpoolIo`. or to own handled iocp via `CreateIoCompletionPort`

Comment: @RbMm: If you need to handle dozens of simultaneous connections then sure, a completion port is going to be necessary.  But if you have an application where communications is not the main purpose, and you just need a remote interface for checking status, then a completion port is counter-productive.  Never introduce threading into a program without a good reason -- the overhead of synchronization will rapidly eat up any performance benefits of completion ports and then some.

Comment: @RbMm: I personally am partial to the APC approach, but introducing `ReadFileEx` doesn't answer the question of how to make `ReadFile` work.

Comment: even for single pipe - `BindIoCompletionCallback` will be good enough and efficient. APC also good (require alertable wait). why i say that use event completion is worst of 3 variants - at first need create event before every io and close (or reuse) after. at second and main - no additional context. say we got that event is signaled. how we get overlapped pointer from this ? need manually map|bind. when in case apc/iocp we got overlapped back, as context pointer. exactly because this it much more better compare event

Comment: @RbMm: That's all a server perspective.  Not every application has a bunch of coequal connections, many have exactly one control pipe.  It's a singleton, with a single pending read operation at all times, so one OVERLAPPED structure and one HANDLE to an event.  Nothing to keep track of.

Comment: even for single connection good enough have correct context, etc. but not use global `OVERLAPPED` etc. and even for single pipe - we can have several io in concurent - both read and write data. my personal choice - iocp. sometime apc completion. never event. but this is everyone chooses for themselves

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.  It seems like making a single call to ReadFile then checking the results with GetOverlappedResult() works well for my purpose.  I haven't tried checking hEvent although I suppose that would be a bit more robust.

Comment: @RbMm I agree with what you say as well. I too prefer what you suggested with IOCP/APC... To me makes more logical sense from a "clean" stand-point at the least even if it is just one connection.